# When connecting to a server using ssh but you do not authenticate using a private key, what key is used to encrypt the data that is transferred?

Tags: authentication, privacy, public-key-infrastructure, ssh, openssh

So I started to use ssh on a server and I noticed that there are two ways of authenticating. I can either just type ssh@username and then provide password or I can use -i command and then select a key file that I have on my drive to give as an argument?

I though the key was necessary to encrypt the communication. If the key file is not provided what is the key used to encrypt the communication?

Answer (score 6):

The users key is used for authentication of the user only, similar to the optional client certificate in TLS (which includes HTTPS). Encryption is done with a key created using a key exchange algorithm like Diffie-Hellman but only after authorizing the server to protect against man in the middle attacks. Insofar is SSH similar to TLS.
For more information have a look at [Understanding the SSH Encryption and Connection Process](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process).

Comment: @SteffenUlrich Thanks, I will read the link to understand better